# Sum php array (created from mysql results) depending on mysql values in another mysql column

Tags: php, mysql

One table called `18_7_ChartOfAccounts` looks like this:

```
ID | AccountNumber
-------------
1  | 2310
2  | 2380
3  | 2610
```

Another table called `2_1_journal` looks like this:

```
ID | Amount | DebitAccount
--------------------------
1  | 26.03  | 2310
2  | 200.00 | 2310
3  | 3.63   | 2380
4  | 119.83 | 2380
5  | 33.86  | 2610
6  | 428.25 | 2610
```

**Aim is to get results that looks like this:**

```
DebitAccount 2310 total is: 226.03
DebitAccount 2380 total is: 123.46
DebitAccount 2310 total is: 462.11
```

226.03 in this example is total of 26.03 + 200.00

At first mysql code

```
$query = "SELECT j.Amount, j.DebitAccount FROM 18_7_ChartOfAccounts AS c LEFT JOIN 2_1_journal AS j ON (c.AccountNumber = j.DebitAccount)";
$sql = $db->prepare($query);
$sql->execute();
$data = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

With `print_r($data);` get long list of arrays like

```
[31] => Array
    (
        [Amount] => 26.03
        [DebitAccount] => 2310

[32] => Array
    (
        [Amount] => 200.00
        [DebitAccount] => 2310
```

If in mysql query use `SUM(j.Amount)` then get only one total amount (suppose total amount of Column `Amount`).

With

```
foreach($data as $result){
if(strlen($result['Amount']) > 0 ) {
echo "Amount ". $result['Amount']. "Account name ". $result['DebitAccount']. "<br>";
print_r (array_sum($result));
}
}
```

Get something like this

```
Amount 123.97Account name 2310
2433.97Amount 26.03Account name 2310
2336.03Amount 200.00Account name 2310
```

Any ideas how to get necessary results (marked bold)?

**Update**

Changed $query to

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(j.Amount), j.DebitAccount FROM 18_7_ChartOfAccounts AS c LEFT JOIN 2_1_journal AS j ON (c.AccountNumber = j.DebitAccount) group by j.DebitAccount";
```

with `print_r($data);` get array like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [SUM(j.Amount)] => 
        [DebitAccount] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [SUM(j.Amount)] => 110900.16
        [DebitAccount] => 2310
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [SUM(j.Amount)] => 3660.86
        [DebitAccount] => 2380
    )
```

With array seems all works. Now with foreach changed to
`echo "Amount ". $result['SUM(j.Amount)']. " Account name ". $result['DebitAccount']. "<br>";`

Get

```
Amount 110900.16 Account name 2310
Amount 3660.86 Account name 2380
Amount 85247.40 Account name 2610
```

Seems also ok. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going about it wrong. You can get the sum through MySql statement itself.

Use the aggrgate function sum along with group by clause.

Like this,

```
SELECT DebitAccount,sum(Account) from  2_1_journal group by DebitAccount
```

Your full code:

```
$query = " SELECT DebitAccount,sum(Account) as Total from  2_1_journal group by DebitAccount";
$sql = $db->prepare($query);
$sql->execute();
$data = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($data as $result){
if(strlen($result['Total']) > 0 ) {
echo "DebitAccount ". $result['DebitAccount']. "Total is: ". $result['Total']. "<br>";
print_r (array_sum($result));
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DebitAccount, SUM(Amount) 
FROM 2_1_journal 
GROUP BY DebitAccount
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `GROUP BY` in the query

```
SELECT DebitAccount, SUM(Amount) AS Amount FROM 2_1_journal GROUP BY DebitAccount
```